# How can I close a channel being populated by multiple goroutines when all work is complete?

Tags: go, asynchronous, channel

I'm trying to follow the Go way of "Do not communicate by sharing memory; instead, share memory by communicating," and using channels to communicate the tasks to be done asyncronously and send back the results of processing the tasks.

For the sake of the simplicity of this example I've changed channels types to int, instead of the structs they really are. And replaced the long processing with a `time.Sleep()`.

How can I close `producedResults` just after sending back all the results of the tasks so this code doesnt get stuck at the last `for`?

```
    quantityOfTasks:= 100
    quantityOfWorkers:= 60
    remainingTasks := make(chan int)
    producedResults := make(chan int)

    // produce tasks
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < quantityOfTasks; i++ {
            remainingTasks <- 1
        }
        close(remainingTasks)
    }()

    // produce workers
    for i := 0; i < quantityOfWorkers; i++ {
        go func() {
            for taskSize := range remainingTasks {
                // simulate a long task
                time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(taskSize))
                // return the result of the long task
                producedResults <- taskSize
            }
        }()
    }

    // read the results of the tasks and agregate them
    executedTasks := 0
    for resultOfTheTask := range producedResults { //this loop will never finish because producedResults never gets closed
        // consolidate the results of the tasks
        executedTasks += resultOfTheTask
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to close that channel after all goroutines writing to it return. You can use a WaitGroup for that:

```
wg:=sync.WaitGroup{}

for i := 0; i < quantityOfWorkers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for taskSize := range remainingTasks {
                //simulate a long task
                time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(taskSize))
                //return the result of the long task
                producedResults <- taskSize
            }
        }()
}

go func() {
  wg.Wait()
  close(producedResults)
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the channel after waiting for the workers to complete.

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(quantityOfWorkers)
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(producedResults)
}()

for i := 0; i < quantityOfWorkers; i++ {
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
    ...
```

https://go.dev/play/p/kdgemc5Unsy

Answer (score 0):

The `producedResults` channel should be closed only after all the worker goroutines have finished their execution. Each worker can signal its completion by either calling `Done()` when using a `WaitGroup` or by closing a dedicated channel.
Burak has already given the example for signalling completion using `WaitGroup`. Code below shows to signal completion using dedicated channels:

```
doneSigs := make([]chan struct{}, quantityOfWorkers)
// produce workers
for i := 0; i < quantityOfWorkers; i++ {
    done := make(chan struct{})
    doneSigs[i] = done
    go func() {
        defer close(done)
        for taskSize := range remainingTasks {
            // simulate a long task
            time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(taskSize))
            // return the result of the long task
            producedResults <- taskSize
        }
    }()
}
go func() {
    defer close(producedResults)
    for i := range doneSigs {
        <-doneSigs[i]
    }
}()
```